# Symbols < and > not showing up

Tags: pdftex, symbols

I'm writing an article using `LaTeX` for the first time.
I need to use symbols `<` and `>` in the body text but they are not displaying, instead they come out as `!` and `?` (upside down).

Can somebody tell me how to fix this?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) it is custom here to provide a small self contained document that others can copy and test as is. Then we have an idea what you are doing and what your document looks like. So please provide such an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `T1` font encoding makes the difference

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}% optional
\begin{document}
<Hello> \textless world\textgreater
\end{document}
```